# Facebook default profile box FBML

Tags: facebook, fbml

I updated an application on Facebook and was trying to provide a new image to show up as a box on a user's profile when they add it.  I added FBML to the default FBML box on the User Profile tab for the application, but it's still showing the old FBML from the previous application.  Googling tells me that this is probably a 'feature' of the Facebook cache, but how can I clear said cache so that users will get the new FBML that I want them to see when they add the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI this question is outdated. Facebook no longer allows default FBML to be set, and profile boxes are not added to profiles by default.

The updated documentation is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/profile.setFBML/

Answer (score 0):

You have two options depending on how it was originally set.

If it was set using a ref handle you can simply update that handle, if however it was set as straight fbml you'll need to loop through all users (must have a db with uids) and update them individually.

Comment: no idea how it was originally set; and I'm not sure I understand either approach in any case.  Users who were never on the old app are still getting the old fbml somehow...